# c# is this how I do override methods?

Tags: c#, methods, overriding

```
    // Loads a users info
    public void loadUserInfo()
    {
        CrystalTech.tblUsersDataTable dsCommon = new CrystalTech.tblUsersDataTable();
        using (tblUsersTableAdapter userAdapter = new tblUsersTableAdapter())
        {
            userAdapter.FillBy(dsCommon, this.ID);
        }
        this.username = dsCommon[0].userName;
        this.company.ID = dsCommon[0].clientID;
        this.company.name = dsCommon[0].ClientName;
        this.isBuyer = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isBuyer.ToString());
        this.isClient = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isClient.ToString());
        this.isClientPowerUser = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].powerUser.ToString());
        this.isReportingUser = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].reportingUser.ToString());
        this.isSupplier = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isSupplier.ToString());
        this.isPaperSupplier = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isPaperSupplier.ToString());
        this.hasKitView = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].haskitview.ToString());
    }
    public void loadUserInfo(int usersID)
    {
        this.ID = usersID;
        loadUserInfo();
    }
```

Is this correct/standard?  Or am I approaching this incorrectly?  The aim is to have the usersID passed in an optional parameter.

Comment: Looks good to me. (the assumption I'm making is that `loadUserInf` is a typo)

Comment: The word you're looking for is "overload", not "override". They're two different concepts. :)

Comment: @Justin Morgan - good catch. I read the question too fast and glazed right over into overload instead of override.

Comment: I've edited it to `loadUserInfo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly what you have done is `method overloading`, `overriding` is something completely different. Assuming it is method overloading you are after and the name of the parametered method is a simple typo, then yes that is how you do it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use optional parameters as of C# 4.0:

```
// Loads a users info
    public void loadUserInfo(int usersID = 0)
    {
        if (usersID > 0) this.ID = usersID;

        CrystalTech.tblUsersDataTable dsCommon = new CrystalTech.tblUsersDataTable();
        using (tblUsersTableAdapter userAdapter = new tblUsersTableAdapter())
        {
            userAdapter.FillBy(dsCommon, this.ID);
        }
        this.username = dsCommon[0].userName;
        this.company.ID = dsCommon[0].clientID;
        this.company.name = dsCommon[0].ClientName;
        this.isBuyer = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isBuyer.ToString());
        this.isClient = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isClient.ToString());
        this.isClientPowerUser = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].powerUser.ToString());
        this.isReportingUser = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].reportingUser.ToString());
        this.isSupplier = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isSupplier.ToString());
        this.isPaperSupplier = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].isPaperSupplier.ToString());
        this.hasKitView = bool.Parse(dsCommon[0].haskitview.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Just thought it's worth mentioning, [Named & Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) are new to VS2010.

Comment: Good point, I'm so used to working with VS 2010 since early release candidates that I forget it's relatively new. Although I suppose a more correct statement would be that they're new to C# 4.0 :)

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have methods with the **same name** but **different parameters** you are correctly overloading.

Assuming that second method is meant to be `loadUserInfo` then yes - this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Tom,

There's nothing wrong with doing it this way, but you don't have to have a different method name to accept the parameter (loadUserInfo vs. loadUserInf).  You can have two different methods with the same name if they accept different parameters.  So you could have:

```
public void loadUserInfo()
```

AND

```
public void loadUserInfo(int usersID)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second one should be `loadUserInfo` but otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting ID as an optional param, you should check out C#'s optional param that is in C# 4.0

http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/02/05/c-4.0-optional-parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Overriding is when you supply a different implementation for an inherited method, what you are doing is overloading.

When overloading, you should use the same name for the methods. Also, it's recommended to name methods using pascal case:

```
// Loads a users info
public void LoadUserInfo() {
  ...
}

public void LoadUserInfo(int usersID) {
  this.ID = usersID;
  loadUserInfo();
}
```